# Class that implements an interface with a method returning List of interfaces generates compilation error

Tags: java, oop

Let's say I have these four classes:

```
public interface A {}

public interface B {
    public A getA();
}

public class C implements A {}

public class D implements B {
    public C getA() {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

This compiles well. However if I have this code I get a compilation error:

```
public interface A {}

public interface B {
    public List<A> getA();
}

public class C implements A {}

public class D implements B {
    public List<C> getA() {
        return new ArrayList<C>();
    }
}

public class E implements B {
    public List<A> getA() {
        return new ArrayList<C>();
    }
}
```

What is the reason that allows to return a C in the method getA, in the first example, but generates an error in the second example when I return a List?

It looks to me that both examples should compile or throw an error.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I read the post using Dog/Animal, however my doubt is different. I have added the class E. If you call getA in class E you get a List as defined in the interface. Then why it fails compiling for class E?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: Hi Tunaki. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is relate to java generics. 
You have defined the return type of method in interface as `List<A>` but you are trying to return a `List<C>` from the actual implementation.
If you actually wanna return a `List<C>` from  the method then you have to change your interface method as follows

```
public List<? extends A> getA();
```

Explanation why can't `return new ArrayList<C>();`

Let say it is valid to return as u mentioned. Then

```
List<A> listA = getA(); // This will compile if allowed
listA.add(new A()); // this will also valid since reference type is A.
```

So you can see that it is no point of allowing the way you mentioned

Comment: Hi Thusitha. Thanks for your reply. Yes, it compiles with your change. What I want to know is why the second example fails. This is just something I want to learn not something I have to make work.

Comment: have you read the explanation given in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p.

Comment: Yes I read, and I still don't why you cannot have an object of type E with a method getA that returns List<A> and internally it returns ArrayList<C>. Is a different thing. In this post it says that if you have a list DEFINED as List<Dog> you cannot use it as a List<Animal>, and I agree. But here is the opposite case. I am returning a list of Animal that contains only Dog. Ok you are free to add cats.